# Stop button isn't stopping my location service

Tags: android, service, gps, intervals, locationlistener

I am trying to write a service which runs with an interval. And each time it runs, it should retrieve the current location of the mobile phone. And as far as it looks my interval is running properly. But as soon as I press the start button, I can't use the stop button anymore to stop it. I've already tried using a Thread, but that one just keeps giving me errors. I've also tried it with a while loop, but somehow my app just crashes.
Anyway this is my code right now:

```
public class Location extends Service {

LocationManager locMan;
LocationListener myLocListener;
int intervalTime = 1000 * 30;
int minTime = 0;
float minDistance = 0;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            //check if GPS is on
            if (!locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Failed to start Location service! Please turn you GPS on!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                stopSelf();
            } else if (locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Service Started",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getLocation();
            }
        }

        private void getLocation() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {

                locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                //while GPS remains on, run this script.
                while (locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

                    myLocListener = new LocationListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onStatusChanged(String provider,
                                int status, Bundle extras) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLocationChanged(
                                android.location.Location location) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            String loc = "Latitude is: "
                                    + location.getLatitude()
                                    + "Longitude is: "
                                    + location.getLongitude();

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    loc,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    };

                    // Specify criteria for a gps provider and get the provider
                    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
                    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
                    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
                    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
                    criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);

                    String BestProvider = locMan.getBestProvider(criteria,
                            false);

                    locMan.requestLocationUpdates(BestProvider,
                            minTime,
                            minDistance,
                            myLocListener);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Location Retrieved",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    handler.postDelayed(this, intervalTime);
                }
                stopSelf();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, intervalTime);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (myLocListener != null) {
        locMan.removeUpdates(myLocListener);
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Service stopped",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are running getLocation() in a Runnable, i guess you need one new handler in your runnable object, and in onDestroy send message to that Handler to stop location listening.

In your runnable inside HandleMessage you can stop listening for location.

How about using **[cwac-locpoll](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll)** library?, it fits your requirements exactly.

Comment: Nope, even then it freezes. And only replies to the home button.

Answer (score 0):

Why not let the service just run, and tell the LocationManager to notify you only at `intervalTime`s. In other words, remove `stopSelf()` and set `minTime` to `1000 * 30`.

Comment: Because it must be possible to stop the service at any time. Without needing to wait for the location when it is running.